# Nat networking in Virtual Box for Windows 7 host and Ubuntu 16.04 not working all of a sudden

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox

I had installed virtualbox on Windows 7 host. Additionally I installed an Ubuntu 16.04 32 bit VM guest. For the network adapter I chose attach to Nat Network. I'm also behind a proxy. Up to last week I had internet connection via the VM. Unfortunately when I checked today I couldn't connect to the internet any more. When I ping the google DNS server 8.8.8.8 I also got Destination Host Unreachable.
I update the Virtualbox to its latest version but no success. In Virtualbox forum I found that I should add Google Dns servers 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 but the internet access could not be retrieved.Has anyone any idea why this may have happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check extension pack is installed and latest version. Check guest additions in ubuntu are installed and latest version.